# Flask download sometimes not starting in Firefox

Tags: flask

I am trying to send a file from Flask to the browser, as it can observed from the code below

```
response = make_response(send_file(os.path.abspath(app.root_path)+server_path,as_attachment=True))
response.mimetype = mimetype # Chosen between "application/zip" and "application/gz"
return response
```

I am not using send_file directly because I need to add extra headers to the response.
The issue is that in Chrome this works flawlessly but when I move to Firefox the download, sometimes, just hangs in the download manager without starting or the download starts but the page will not refresh.
What could be the cause of this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Is that the full code example, or are you doing other things to the response? Are there other extra headers are you adding at some point? And are you saying it works on firefox when you try `send_file` without wrapping it in a `make_response` first?

Also, depending on which version of flask you're using, `send_file` supports adding an argument to the method for mimetype, see the documentation: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.send_file so there might not be a reason for you to wrap it with the `make_response` function.

Comment: To answer your questions:
- That's the only code related to the response. I am not adding anything else.
- No, when I try send_file on firefox it still does not work sometimes, while sometimes it does not.
- I need the make_response because I need to add extra headers to the response and send_file does not allow me to do so

Comment: You will have to be more specific in that case, under what conditions or scenarios does it work? Is it for certain files, file types, directories on the server or what?Also, what headers do you mean? As I `mentioned send_file` should support mimetype as an argument, so if that is the only one you're adding wrapping it in a `make_response` should not be necessary.

Comment: I can't seem to figure out why it works sometimes while sometimes it does not. The code is the same. The file extension does not matter either, because I tried with different ones. I want to add an extra header to let the browser know that the download has started to trigger an event on download start.

Comment: But when and where do you add extra headers, and what are they? I cannot see it in your short snippet, from what I see you only add the mimetype. Please post all the relevant code for making and editing this response.

Comment: I am trying to get the send_file to work properly before adding the extra headers, that's why they are not there

Comment: It will be hard to help if you do not show all the relevant code for how you are handling the response. Please edit the question with all relevant code, and perhaps try investigate further under which situations it works on firefox, for example by removing logic little by little until it works and you find what in the code or browser triggers this behaviour.